# how much time is passed from a certain event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to show an info - how much time is passed from a certain event.

For example:

```
var event = '2017-04-25 09:20:00';
var datea = new Date(event);
var dateb = new Date();
var diff = Math.abs(dateb.getTime() - datea.getTime());
var days = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
var hours = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 3600));
var mins = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 60));
var sec = Math.ceil(diff / (1000));
```

But this are all total values of `days`, `hours`... etc.

I want to show the info this way:

THE EVENT HAPPENS `xYears xMonths xDays xHours xMins xSecs` AGO

How to calculate and display the info in the above way?

`Years` and `Months` may be rounded on `365` and `30` days.

Also the info should be updated on each second.

Any help?

Comment: check out http://momentjs.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), which is the most reliable date library I know, it would look like this:

```js
// your date
var event = '2017-04-25 09:20:00';

// Moment objects to compare
var datea = moment(event,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
var now = moment();

// Find the difference
var diff = now.diff(datea);
var d = moment.duration(diff);

// Resulting object
console.log(d._data);

// Formatting...
$("span").html(d._data.years+" years, "+
               d._data.months+" months, "+
               d._data.days+" days, "+
               d._data.hours+" hours, "+
               d._data.minutes+" minutes, "+
               d._data.seconds+" seconds");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<span></span>
```

Look for these moment methods:

- [parsing formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)
- [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)
- [difference](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Comment: Moment is full of methods to do whatever you wish with date and time using very few lines of code. The documentation deserves a reading. Have fun! ;)

Comment: moment.fromNow() ?

Comment: `.fromNow()` just outputs a string... like "2 years ago." OP needed all the details which I found in the returned object from `.duration()`.